# Get Description of a keyword using category.GetListKeywords()

Tags: 2013-sp1, tom.net

I am using `category.GetListKeywords(KeywordsFilter)` to get the keyword list of a category. The fetched keyword list xml looks like below:

```
<tcm:ListKeywords xmlns:tcm="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0" Managed="0">
<tcm:Item ID="tcm:6-5256-1024" Title="Level1 - Test Keyword1" Allow="268560384" Deny="96" Icon="T1024L0P0" Type="1024" IsNew="false" Modified="2015-05-05T11:14:20" IsShared="false" IsLocalized="false" Lock="0" Key="" IsAbstract="false" IsRoot="true" CategoryID="tcm:6-5039-512" CategoryTitle="Test Category"/>
</tcm:ListKeywords>
```

But the item element for keyword missing the "Description" field.

Is there any way to get "Description" as an attribute of the xml element?

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that you can't... I tried using this to get Tridion to return the full objects, but it will not return the description. This unfortunately happens a lot with their API. you tell it to get the full object and SDL thinks it's helping you by saving bandwidth by returning a "lightweight" result. The only option is to get the lightweight version and then requery to get a full object.

```
$filter = New-Object Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData
$filter.BaseColumns = 3
```

Comment: This answer would be so much better without the snark :D

Comment: actually, if I'm not mistaken, a pretty high-ranking SDL-er pretty much stated the above to me.

Comment: If you want to know the real reason why mosts list return partially loaded objects, you may want to take a look at the DB Stored Procedures for getting the list data and those for reading an individual item (and then imagine combining both is a single humongous one without driving yourself and the query optimizer crazy :-)

Comment: Also note that many filters support "additional columns" (filter properties named "IncludeXYZColumn") next to "base columns". In particular: IncludeDescription is such an additional column on some filters. Not sure if it applies to this filter, though.

Comment: @Rick Pannekoek: it does not include that option. only one like that is IncludeAllowedActionsColumns.

Answer (score 1):

Using TOM.NET API, we can get description field of a keyword. Sample code below:

```
TcmUri categoryURI = new TcmUri(itemId, ItemType.Category, Publication.Id.ItemId);
Category category = Engine.GetObject(categoryURI) as Category;
IList<Keyword> keywords = category.GetKeywords().ToList();
foreach (Keyword keyword in keywords)
{
//keyword.Description
}
```

Comment: Murali, I want to fetch the XML list of keywords (under a category), not the keyword objects. Fetching keyword objects is not a good idea considering performance.

Answer (score 0):

Using CoreService you can get the keywords list xml within a category which also has the description. It comes as "comment" attribute/property in the xml that comes back from CoreService. The below line of code will bring the xml with all keyword fields
`var keywordList = coreserviceclient.GetListXml(ID, taxonomyFilter);`

where ID can be the publication ID of the category and taxonomy filter can be set for the category for which keywords are needed

Comment: Okay, but i want it in templating TOM.NET code. I think i can use coreservice in templating but not sure if its the right way to achive it.

Comment: Using the Core Service in templating code is indeed not a good idea. But note that the Core Service is a Service Layer built on top of the TOM.NET API. So that means that *all* functionality exposed in the Core Service is also available in the TOM.NET.  In case of list, the filter type will help you find the associated TOM.NET method.